# Referencing an Excel address within a cell, but also additional text

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to insert a reference into a cell with arbitrary text around it.

ex. use a reference to cells A1, B1

```
  C1 => "blah blah <A1 text> foobar <B1 text>"
```

Is there any way to do something like this while still maintaining the references?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have a **[couple of options](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052090201033.aspx)**:

& operator:

```
="blah blah " & A1 & " foobar " & B1
```

or CONCATENATE():

```
=CONCATENATE("blah blah ",A1," foobar ",B1)
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew there had to be a simple way.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
=CONCATENATE("blah blah ", A1, " foobar ", B1)
```

Put the above formula in cell C1.